# Convert SQL to LINQ: select the result into model

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm not familiar with LINQ, can any one help me out?
Thanks in advance.

My model:

```
public class OrderOverViewModel
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public String ACCN { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS HowMany, 
       DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, RXS_OrderDate)) AS OrderDate, 
       RXS_ACCN  AS ACCN  
FROM RXS_RxJobs
WHERE DATEDIFF(WK, RXS_OrderDate, GETDATE()) = 1
GROUP BY RXS_ACCN, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, RXS_OrderDate))
```

The result in SSMS:

[image]

I want the select result fill the model, how to acchieve this?
Thanks again.

Comment: Is it LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities? Ans what you have tried so far?

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky :LINQ to SQL, i can attach the result screenshot in SSMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [SqlFunctions.DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487052.aspx) method to get weeks between current date and order date. Also you can simply get date part of date via `Date` property of `DateTime` object. Query should look like this:

```
from j in context.RXS_RxJobs
    .Where(x => SqlMethods.DateDiffDay(x.RXS_OrderDate, DateTime.Now) >= 7 &&
                SqlMethods.DateDiffDay(x.RXS_OrderDate, DateTime.Now) < 14)
group j by new { j.RXS_ACCN, j.RXS_OrderDate.Date } into g
select new OrderOverViewModel
{
   Quantity = g.Count(),
   ACCN =  g.Key.RXS_ACCN,
   OrderDate = g.Key.Date  
};
```

UPDATE (for Linq to Entities):

```
from j in context.RXS_RxJobs
    .Where(x => SqlFunctions.DateDiff("wk", x.RXS_OrderDate, DateTime.Now) == 1)
group j by new { 
    j.RXS_ACCN, 
    Date = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(j.RXS_OrderDate).Value
} into g
select new OrderOverViewModel {
   Quantity = g.Count(),
   ACCN =  g.Key.RXS_ACCN,
   OrderDate = g.Key.Date 
};
```

Comment: @Wayou very glad to here that!

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky :the 'Date' in 'j.RXS_OrderDate.Date' caused error: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: @Wayou according to error, you are using Linq to Entities. Query should be modified for that

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky：I'm sorry it's LINQ to Entities. Now I changed the 'Date' to 'Day', but how I can assign the g.Key.Day(int) to OrderDate(datetime), I want to store datetime into OrderDate as the screenshot above.

Comment: @Wayou I've updated answer with linq to entities. It works for me. Let me know if it works in your case

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky ： It's so kind of you! In your updated version, the last expression can't compile:  cannot convert source type system.nullable<system.datetime> to target type system.datetime.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Curious, will SqlFunctions work in linq to entities? I mostly used EntityFunctions in EF.

Comment: @Danny yes, it works in EF. Actually looks like it do not work in Linq to SQL :) Linq to SQL should use `SqlMethods` instead (updated answer) but there is not diif for weeks :(

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky :I modified my model to accept nullable value. Now no error any more. Great appreciate.

Comment: @Wayou update again :) You should use `.Value` when grouping results

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky: Your last updated version works now without modify my model to 'DateTime?' . Thanks.

Comment: @Wayou yes, you can use your original model :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var viewModels = from job in ObjectContext.RXS_RxJobs
where SqlFunctions.DateDiff("Day", RXS_OrderDate,DateTime.Now) == 1
group job by new { RXS_ACCN, OrderDate} into jobGroup
select new OrderOverViewModel
{ 
    Quantity = jobGroup.Count(),
    ACCN =  jobGroup.Key.RXS_ACCN,
    OrderDate = jobGroup.Key.OrderDate
} ;
```

Comment: Also thank you. However, there are error in your code. I don't know how to fix it. VS says the job is declared in bleow.